# Avoid infinite loop using onload event

Tags: javascript, jsp, loops, onload, infinite

I'm pretty new at javascript and I've encountered a problem:
I 've a method which calls an Action through a button in my jsp page.

The thing is, I want to execute this Action immediately after loading my jsp page, without having to use the button event.

I'm trying to use the onload() event inside the body of the JSP. This does executes my Action after loading, however, it stays in an infinite loop, because it loads the page over and over again.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function send()
    {
        document.forms['thisForm'].submit(); 
    }
</script    
....
<body onload="send()">

<html:form action="/something/foo.do?method=methodFoo" method="post">
```

Is there anyway to avoid this infinite loop?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: refactor your code to not submit a form everytime a page is loaded

Comment: It sounds like 'submit()' must cause your body to load again. How else could there be an infinite loop?

Comment: @mareoraft *must cause*, when you submit a form the browser sends a request. The request unless `return false` refreshes the browser. The browser refreshes and sees: `send()`, and all over again...

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to execute your action without submiting the form.

Comment: I can't use AJAX in the current environment of the project in which I'm working on :/

Comment: That's the only way I see. You can try refactoring your code to navigate to another page that will not have the 'submit()' again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential ways to solve this, but I will start with the one I like the best:

```
BODY onLoad="window.location.href='EXAMPLE.html';" onUnload="send();"
```

What happens here is that the first thing it does is pass you to a new web page ("EXAMPLE.html") but it has to run your JavaScript when it is exiting. By doing this it is unable to get into the infinite loop.

Another approach:

```
BODY onLoad="send();window.close();"
```

With this one it will attempt to close the window after running your command. I am not a big fan of this because that window.close command can behave differently depending on the browser they use, and it almost always needs the individual to agree to close it. But, it might work for you.